# Kubectl Get Worker Nodes Only

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any shortcut or kubectl command or REST API call to get a list of worker nodes only. ( not including the master nodes )

**Update**:
For the masters we can do like this:

```
kubectl get nodes --selector=node-role.kubernetes.io/master
```

for the workers I dont see any such label created by default. Can we do get by reversing or do != kind of thing on selector.

We can't grep it either:

```
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ kubectl get nodes | grep worker
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ kubectl get nodes -o wide| grep worker
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep worker
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ 
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$ kubectl get nodes -o json | grep worker
C02W84XMHTD5:ucp iahmad$
```

My use case is that want to get this list every minute to update the external load balancer pools, in case new nodes are added, removed from the cluster. Indeed I can label them myself but if there is some default built in way of doing this would be useful

Comment: `kubectl get nodes | grep worker` does not do the job?

Comment: Thanks ,I will try that , but I am looking for some cleaner way not to use external tool like grep , because i will need this inside python sdk for k8s api.

Comment: @christoph nope , it didnt work

Answer (score 10):

You can get roles/labels of your nodes by

```
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
```

in my case, I do have three nodes each having the given roles and labels:

```
NAME        STATUS    ROLES                      AGE       VERSION   LABELS
host01      Ready     controlplane,etcd,worker   61d       v1.10.5   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=host01,node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true
host02      Ready     etcd,worker                61d       v1.10.5   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=host02,node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true
host03      Ready     etcd,worker                61d       v1.10.5   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=host03,node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true
```

Only host01 has the label `controlplane, worker` and `etcd`. The other two have `etcd` and `worker` (Scroll right to see the labels as well).

So I can get all worker nodes by

```
kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true

NAME        STATUS    ROLES                      AGE       VERSION
host01      Ready     controlplane,etcd,worker   61d       v1.10.5
host02      Ready     etcd,worker                61d       v1.10.5
host03      Ready     etcd,worker                61d       v1.10.5
```

To exclude `controlplane`s, you can exclude them with a second label by `!=true`

```
kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane!=true

NAME        STATUS    ROLES         AGE       VERSION
host02      Ready     etcd,worker   61d       v1.10.5
host03      Ready     etcd,worker   61d       v1.10.5
```

Please adapt that to your labels or set labels accordingly to your cluster. In my case it is a [Rancher 2.0](https://rancher.com/) cluster. The labels are automatically created by Rancher when added a node.

The API for that is in Rancher at (with the filter already appended):

```
/v3/clusters/c-xxxxx/nodes?worker=true&controlPlane_ne=true
```

Comment: hmmm don't have those labels, I will need to create a feature request to docker ee

Comment: This should not be left to k8s operator to put labels on master and worker nodes , there should be a built stadandard way of doing this , maybe i will put labels on my worker nodes now , but a new admin adding a new node tommorow may not , or may forget to put the label , so it wont show up in the worker lists to the remote system using the list

Comment: How do you usually add nodes? Which kind of cluster do you have?

Comment: Its docker EE , I just install a new docker EE node and add it to existing cluster using UCP

Comment: Those lables should be added by kubernetes by default , regardless of the deployment tool

Comment: The underlying docker is not relevant here. When adding a node to an k8s cluster you can also set labels. Please see  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#self-registration-of-nodes

Comment: ofcourse you can add labels anytime , but this is something should be there wihtout adding them by the user

Comment: If you want you can create a github issue and request a feature like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following to select workers

```
kubectl get node --selector='!node-role.kubernetes.io/master'
```

Comment: On later k8s versions, go with: 
kubectl get node --selector='!node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane'

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
kubectl describe node -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true
```