# Kubernetes master node restrict to show

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a kubernetes cluster

In Master node,

If I give the command `kubectl get nodes` it should show all the nodes.

But, If I give the same command in nodes it should not show the master node.

Is it possible in kubernetes?

Please help anyone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you want this to be the case?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My case is master server should not expose to others. Because, I will install my own agents in master servers. So users should not understand about master servers.

Comment: So you have users that have access to the cluster, but you don't want them to be able to run workloads on the master nodes? There is [an issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48041) that might describe such a case. One recommendation there is running this [admission controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d490e2cf83316dfa302e54842e91752a029d5210/plugin/pkg/admission/podtolerationrestriction/admission.go) to prohibit new pods that try to tolerate running on the master nodes. I am not sure how to set that up though.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The kubernetes API will always respond to the same queries in the same way. `kubectl get nodes` is asking for information about all nodes, and the api will always answer an authorized user with all of the nodes.

With RBAC it is possible to limit what a particular user or account has access to view or edit, but the `nodes` resource is not namespaced, and does not give granularity to restrict access to certain nodes.

You can, however, filter the results of `kubectl get nodes` any way you like. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434076/121660) has some good examples of showing only worker nodes using the `-l` argument to kubectl.

Comment: I think it's possible. I have checked in [digitalocean.com](https://cloud.digitalocean.com). In this server, if access kubectl get nodes it will not show the master server.

Comment: I imagine digitalocean is running a patched version of the kubernetes api server that does not return the master nodes from such calls.

Comment: Or maybe they are just running the apiserver from outside of the cluster and there literally are no master nodes at all. Only workers.