# How to get all nodes with status 'Ready' except master node(s)?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the `kubernetes` `cli` command that will list all nodes with state "Ready" except master node(s) ?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433599/kubectl-get-worker-nodes-only ? Use that and then grep for status ready

Comment: These are two different questions. The other question ask about worker nodes and in answer uses grep. This questions does not mentions grep. It should be pure `kubectl command` without piping it with `grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
$ kubectl get nodes --selector '!node-role.kubernetes.io/master' --output jsonpath="{.items[?(@.status.conditions[-1].type=='Ready')].status.conditions[-1].type}"
```

**Explenation:**

Selector flag `--selector '!node-role.kubernetes.io/master'` excludes all nodes that does not match `node-role.kubernetes.io/master` label.

Output flag `--output jsonpath="{.items[?(@.status.conditions[-1].type=='Ready')].status.conditions[-1].type}"` matches nodes, which last conditions is in Ready state - this turns out to be status of KubeletReady.

**Edit:** More elegant solution

```
$ kubectl get nodes --selector '!node-role.kubernetes.io/master' --output jsonpath="{range .items[?(@.status.conditions[-1].type=='Ready')]}{.metadata.name} {.status.conditions[-1].type}{'\n'}{end}"
```

Comment: Nice usage of selector flag

Answer (score -1):

$ kubectl get nodes --selector '!node-role.kubernetes.io/master'

Comment: Down voted because you are checking only for a label. This will display only master nodes in the cluster independently if they are running or not. Moreover, all worker nodes are omitted in this answer.